# Google Bar Chart custom tooltip does not work

Tags: google-visualization

This code:

```
chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('string', '');
dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Value');
dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {'html': true}});
var rows = [
    ['U.S.', 2, "tool"],
    ['France', 10, "tip"]
];
dataTable.addRows(rows);
chart.draw(dataTable);
```

does not result in a custom tooltip.

Strangely it works with other chart types.

Do you know why please?

[edit] Apparently this is not possible. Is there any other way to put a "%" symbol in the tooltip, like in this screenshot?

[image]

Comment: simply doesn't work on _Material_ charts, nor does `role: 'style'`...

Comment: Thanks, but Material charts are much prettier than Classics :( I edited my question in the hope we can solve the problem in another way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tooltip should show the formatted value by default.
Using object notation for your values, you can provide a formatted value (`f:`)
along with the required value (`v:`)...

you can also use `dataTable.setFormattedValue(...)` after the table is loaded...

Example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['bar']
});

function drawChart() {
  chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart'));
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  dataTable.addColumn('string', '');
  dataTable.addColumn('number', 'Value');
  var rows = [
      ['U.S.', {v: 2, f: '2%'}],    // add %
      ['France', {v: 10, f: '10%'}],  // add %
      ['Germany', {v: 15, f: 'whatever we want'}]   // add whatever we want 
  ];
  dataTable.addRows(rows);
  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: edit: just realized, supplying a formatted value allows you to provide any format you want. not sure if it will render html...? -- check it out...

Comment: btw: tried versions `'42'` thru `'current'` on getting tooltip to work in _Material_ chart...

Comment: Thanks a lot!! This works great, and for labels too. No it does not render HTML.

Comment: This is incredible, thank you!
How did you find that out? I wonder because I'd like to see what are all the options for each chart type.
I don't understand why the documentation does not cover that and why do we have multiple chart types that are actually the same? For example Bar and BarChart - each one has it's own list of options and rules...

Comment: been using google charts a while now -- `bar` is considered a [_Material Chart_](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#creating-material-column-charts) whereas `barchart` comes from the original `corechart` package -- as for values and formatted values, see the [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#datatable-class) reference...